# How does MMO flash games works?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mmo

I want to know how does MMO flash games work, for example: Dofus and Club Penguin.

I want to know if by ony using Adobe Flash and ActionScript you can do MMO games, or if there is other way to work with ActionScript and Flash beyond Adobe Flash.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that your question is inappropriate for this site, and will probably end being closed. Because it's asking how X game does Y. This question doesn't have a correct answer and will end up with many speculations, I never used flash, but regardless of that, flash is somehow similar to other *engines*, engines and games structure things with different techniques and code setups, so it could be similar to any of the things you mentioned. And btw you need to define what *big* means.

Comment: thank you,i reformulated my question to be more clearly :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments no answer could really be definitive here, but you must be aware of the fact that Flash is getting more and more deprecated, that Games like Dofus have a very strict production process (and huge library of code) to overcome the fragilities of Flash.

To answer your questions:

- You *can* make MMOs with flash *but*, with the current state of technology it does not
  mean you should.
- Adobe Flash is an IDE for Flash devs and artists, it is developed by Adobe, the creators of Flash so despite the fact that some free platform exist you will *hardly* find better,
- In our days and time, there is new technologies which will provide
  more integrated results, for example HTML5 and Ajax (or if you like adobe, Adobe Air).

I tell all that because if you ask this question it is probably that you want to start a project but do not know the technology (no harm in that :D ) and to save you time and money I strongly suggest you to learn HTML5 as it will always be useful later.

To go back to Dofus, people over there are very talented and they are using Flash because at the time they created Dofus it was the best API providing the Art/Code balance they needed (Art in Dofus it the state of the Art in terms of vector art...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actualy,it was a doubt i had when i started making games,my first experience was with flash,and i aways wondered about this games.But now i'm using Unity 3d.